# Crop and reproject TIFF to match bounds, pixel size of second TIFF

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I have this working but I'm wondering if there's a better/faster way.

Currently, I use the following which creates an intermediate file (rasterb_cropped) from gdal.Warp() then creates the reprojected image with a call to gdal.ReprojectImage().

```
rastera_handle      = gdal.Open( rastera, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly )
rastera_proj        = rastera_handle.GetProjection()
rastera_trans       = rastera_handle.GetGeoTransform()
rastera_band        = rastera_handle.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
rastera_xsize       = rastera_handle.RasterXSize
rastera_ysize       = rastera_handle.RasterYSize


# 1) crop rasterb to bounds
gdal.Warp( rasterb_cropped, rasterb_orig, outputBounds=[ lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 ], cropToCutline=True )

rasterb_handle      = gdal.Open(rasterb_cropped, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
inputProj           = rasterb_handle.GetProjection()
NoDataIn            = rasterb_handle.GetRasterBand(1).GetNoDataValue()


driver              = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
rasterb_final       = driver.Create( outputfile, rastera_xsize, rastera_ysize, 1, rastera_band )
rasterb_final.SetGeoTransform( rastera_trans )
rasterb_final.SetProjection( rastera_proj )
rasterb_final.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue( NoDataIn )

# 2) reproject rasterb to match pixel size (etc) of rastera
gdal.ReprojectImage( rasterb_handle, rasterb_final, inputProj, rastera_proj, gdalconst.GRA_Average )
```

Comment: See if this solution works for you. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/354380/37262

Comment: It's working well and a bit faster. This is extremely helpful!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I currently have after looking over the solution @wondim linked to. Still testing since this doesn't specifically set the GeoTransform or Projection.

```
rastera_handle      = gdal.Open( rastera, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly )
rastera_trans       = rasterafile.GetGeoTransform()
rastera_xres        = str(abs(rastera_trans[1]))
rastera_yres        = str(abs(rastera_trans[5]))

gdal.Warp( rasterb_final, rasterb, xRes = rastera_xres, yRes = rastera_yres, outputBounds=rastera_bounds )
```

Comment: This solution does not define `rastera_bounds` used in the last line.